# Play Framework and JNotify

Tags: java, playframework, jnotify

When starting a play framework application I get this notice:

```
Cannot load the JNotify native library (/home/myapplication/target/native_libraries/32bits/libjnotify.so: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.12' not found (required by /home/myapplication/target/native_libraries/32bits/libjnotify.so))
Play will check file changes for each request, so expect degraded reloading performace.
```

I'm not able to update this server. How much "degraded reloading performace" there will be? How worried should I be :-) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be several things, either the wrong shared object is loaded (are you really on a 32bit system?) or you just need to compile JNotify yourself on your system because the that is compiled for you does not match the version of glibc.

Comment: How to compile it like that?